# Fortran code to read formatted data file record wise

Tags: fortran

I got a Fortran code for K-means clustering from online.
As I am new to Fortran, I do not have an idea about the required input file format for the code as below.

How to prepare an input file according to this Fortran code?

```
    infile1='D1_TR_all_cent63.dat'
    OPEN(1,FILE=infile1,form='formatted',access='direct',
 +  recl=429)

      istep=nvectors/nclusters
      DO i=1,nclusters

        READ(1,23,rec=istep*(i-1)+1)(vec(j),j=1,42)
        DO k=1,nelements 
         centroid(i,k)=vec(k)
        END DO
      END DO
 23     format(42(f10.3))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a file where each line contains 42 fields where it expects to find fixed point numbers.  That's the `42(f10.3)` in the `format`
statement. Each of those fields is 10 characters wide; there are no commas or other separator characters between them, although spaces are allowed.

For example:

```
123456.789   123.123  -123.123 12345.678     0.000
```

(and onward until there are 42 of those).

Most FORTRAN implementations will be a bit merciful on reading:  You can leave off some of the after-decimal point digits, or have a space after the number (but you have to stay in the 10-character fields).  But not all do, so it might be better to prepare your input with 6 digits (including sign, if needed, and allowing spaces instead) before the decimal point and three after.

Comment: It may be useful to be precise on what the format requires - I don't expect there to be much "mercy".  Processors will largely do what is required of them.

Comment: The access to the file is direct.  There could be many lines in the file which aren't of this form (depending on `istep`) and the `format` given specifies what is required of the accessed records only.

Comment: "processors will largely do what is required of them": true.  But there were a _lot_ of FORTRAN runtime vendors, and many of the runtimes went to some trouble to accept a broad array of conditions, beyond the bare minimum that the standards required.  f77, for example, doesn't care where the decimal point is so long as there's only zero or one in each field.  So if there's an easy way to prepare a file with a "close" format, that might be worth trying.

Comment: For example, the effect of reading `1234567890` with edit descriptor `F10.3` is precisely determined by the Fortran standard and that standard very much cares that `1234567890` is not `12345.6789`.

Comment: Thank you for response.  Can anyone help to explain a meaning of "recl=429" in second line where it opens a file?

Comment: note the record length of 429 characters, yet you only read 420 characters of data. The input needs to be padded with 9 extra characters for each data set.  Also if `istep` is not `1` you need blocks of 429 characters (times `istep-1`) in between the data sets.  (all this assumes you are not allowed to change the read source code.. )